# How to fix 'Your PC can't project to another screen' after win 8.1 updating?

Tags: windows-8, hp-envy

After updating to win 8.1 from Win 8, I could not project to another screen. Message says

> Your PC can't project to another screen

I tried to re-install the diver and did not resolve the issue.

Comment: What drivers did you try to reinstall exactly?

Answer (score 1):

My machine has Intel and NVIDIA cards.

I tried many times to re-install the Nvidia driver and changed to the new version but cannot resolve this issue. Then I changed to a new method. I changed the Intel driver instead and got a newer version. It worked for me!

I fixed it by:

1. disabling "Intel HD Graphics driver" (not Nvidia)
2. installing the "HD Graphics diver" with new version (download from Intel website)
3. restarting the machine

Answer (score -1):

After a long research to solve this problem I found a simple and effective solution
install software "Display Driver Uninstaller"
uninstall the graphics card drivers with this software then restart your PC and it works

Comment: I would strongly advise NOT using Display Driver Uninstaller.  I have seen hundreds of questions about problems caused by this application.